Resizing iframe from JavaScript results high CLS
I have an iframe on my site that displays a list. At the bottom of the list there is a "See more" button, once the user presses it, the list will expand. The iframed site uses parent.postMessage to notify my site of the height changes:
parent.postMessage({"height": height}, targetOrigin);

On my site, I listen to this message and update the iframe's height by code:
window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
  if (event.data.height) {
    const iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
    iframe.height = event.data.height;
  }
});

However clicking inside the iframe does not count as user interaction on the site, so by expanding the iframe from JavaScript it results as "unexpected layout shift" once the content below the iframe is pushed down.
I tried to delay the height change with setTimeout, and also added transition css rule to the iframe's height, but still getting high CLS numbers. I also tried to add a button on the site and once the message arrives, I trigger a click event on it, and handle the resize from that, but it didn't help at all.
I can ask the iframed site to modify their code, if necessary. Also the new height is dynamic, so I won't know it until the message arrives.
How to solve the CLS issue, while having the resize in place?
Edit: Answering KIKO Software for clarification.
The site's CLS score for real user data is around 0.7-0.9. I get this number from PageSpeed Insights and from a Chrome extension. I suspect the "See more" button, because nothing else on the site moves or loads. Also I installed a Chrome extension (CLS visualizer) that shows the shifts upon interaction.
Since the CLS is part of the Web Vitals, my page is getting worse ranking by search engines if it's high, that is why I'm concerned.

CLS, or Cumulative Layout Shift, is a tool to help you design better user experiences. Your question is vague on several points: 1. How high is the CLS score? 2. Why do think it this due to the "See more" button? 3. How do you measure CLS? We don't all use the same tools. 4. If your site is functioning as desired, why do you care? In the end, what you're trying to do isn't abnormal, so why is this such a problem? (Don't tell me: Rumors about SEO?)

Thank you for your answer and questions. I answered them as an edit to my question, so it can clarify these to other users as well.

Thanks for the update. That is indeed a high score. To be really sure it is the button in the iframe you could create the same page with an iframe, but remove the "See more" button from its content. That would take five minutes, and prevents you from potentially wasting time chasing ghosts. I still find it weird that such a simple thing would carry such a heavy penalty.

It might simply be that the dimensions of the iframe depend on its content when you first load the page. That will cause layout shifts, but it has nothing to do with the "See more" button.

I get the initial dimensions of the iframe and set them up as such. So having a fixed value for height and width is in place. According to the "CLS visualizer" all good on the page, if I scroll down to the "See more" just as the iframe's bottom is aligned with my screen's bottom, then press the button, still all good. The problem occurs when I have the bottom of the iframe at the middle or higher up on the page, and my site's content is visible on the screen. Then I press the button, the iframe expands and pushes my site's content down.

Coming to this as the author of iframe-resizer.
You can reduce visible layout shifts on page load, by setting the initial height of the iframe to 100vh. That way once the content loads, it will either shrink into view, which stops the jarring effect, or it will expand below the fold, where again it will have no jarring effect on the user.
Updating the iframe via postMessage after the page in the iframe loads more content you will have to accept this is never going to have the browser think it was the result of user interaction. If this is important to you then you need to run the iframe on the same-origin as the parent page, so you can communicate directly via JS, without using message passing.
A better question is how is the content being added to the iframe. I would look to see if there is a lot of content shifting going on when that happens. Ideally you should render all the added content in one go with all page elements correctly sized and then send a single postMessage to the parent page.
